# Mdframed, multicol, and weird page breaks

Tags: page-breaking, multicol, mdframed

I see some similarities to other questions ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46873/mdframed-bug-with-page-break) and [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109817/interaction-with-multicol-and-mdframed-results-in-misaligned-rows)), but I think this is distinct. When I use `mdframed` and `multicol` together, I sometimes get bizarre unintended pagebreaks. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcount\myloopcounter
\newcommand{\repeatit}[2][10]{%
\myloopcounter0% initialize the loop counter
\loop\ifnum\myloopcounter < #1 % Test if the loop counter is < #1
#2%
\advance\myloopcounter by 1 % 
\repeat % start again
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\repeatit[30]{
\vspace{0.3cm}
\begin{mdframed}
\vspace{3cm}
\end{mdframed}
}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Credit to [Christian Hupfer's answer to another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300212/12991) for `repeatit` which allows me to express this MWE more concisely. When I run this MWE, I get 10 frames on the first page. Then I get only one frame on the second page before it breaks to the third page. Just one frame on the fourth page, and then the frames on the fifth page are misaligned. What's going on?

A few additional details: Sometimes I don't get any weird page breaks. It seems to depend on how everything fits in the page before the break occurs. Also, sometimes the weird page break appears within a frame, so there is just 2/3 of a frame on one page, and then the frame resumes on the next page.

Comment: Thanks for the credits to my answer there -- it was however not meant to be used this way with `multicols` etc. Depending what you're really after, a `tcbraster` from `tcolorbox` package can be easier here!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer In my actual document, I don't use it. I just use it here for a MWE because it saves me having 30 blank boxes. That's to say that the strange behavior I'm seeing occurs without `repeatit`, which I only use to demonstrate the behavior cleanly in the MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around the problem by adding an additional box:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcount\myloopcounter
\newcommand{\repeatit}[2][10]{%
\myloopcounter0% initialize the loop counter
\loop\ifnum\myloopcounter < #1 % Test if the loop counter is < #1
#2%
\advance\myloopcounter by 1 %
\repeat % start again
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\repeatit[30]{%
\vspace{0.3cm}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{mdframed}
\vspace{3cm}
\end{mdframed}
\end{minipage}\par
}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

But I would instead follow the advice of Christian and use tcolorbox -- it is much more stable than mdframed.